# Gulp + BrowserSync proxy not loading

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, gulp, browser-sync

I have a PHP webserver on my machine that runs on port `5000`.

I am trying to get a browserSync proxy with gulp to auto-refresh it, however it is not working without returning any error. I can access the page on port `5000`, so the server is up, and I can access the browserSync UI, so the process for that is up as well.

Here is my gulp

```
function watch(){
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "0.0.0.0:5000",
        port: 5001,
        files: ['*.html', '**/*.css', '**.*.js', '**.*.php']
    });
    gulp.watch("src/**/*.php", reload);
}
```

And here is the console output from running it:

```
$ gulp watch
[02:51:57] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[02:51:57] Starting 'watch'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (index.css)
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (index.js)
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:5000
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:5001
    External: http://192.168.128.1:5001
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

Don't know if it matters, but the webserver is a vscode extention: "PHP Server". I also already saw the similar questions but none of the answers worked, and I do not have malwareBytes installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

After reading somewhere (don't remember where) that `localhost` can cause problems, I changed the server settings to run off `127.0.0.1:5000` and the browserSync to proxy that and it worked

Comment: Exactly that. I have mine gulpfile working just fine when out of nowhere it stopped working. Changed to 127.0.0.1 and all good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using BrowserSync 3.0.2 and I couldn't access the site at all. I was using the code with proxy

```
browserSync.init({
  proxy: "local.build",
  baseDir: "build/"
});
```

I guess it was possible to add an entry in `/etc/hosts` to make the proxy resolve to loopback `::1   local.build` and then configure Apache's virtual host configuration, but I resolved that simpler by using a server instead of proxy to Apache

```
browserSync.init({
  server: {
    baseDir: "build/"
  }
});
```

and adding the entry to the `/etc/hosts`: `::1 pop-os.localdomain  pop-os` (IPv4 was there already, it lacked only IPv6), and then I executed `gulp watch` again and it worked.